# Split String( String contains Regular expression)

Tags: ruby

I want to split the last string from given path, that string contains some numbers like 1.625.235, but this numbers vary every time. Irrespective of the number that last string should be split.

Ex:

```
string = "C:/chef/cache/Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-1.625.235.msi"
output:  Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-1.625.235.msi

string = "C:/chef/cache/Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-1.181.539.msi"
output:  Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-1.181.539.msi
```

This is what we tried

- ("C:/chef/cache/Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-/\d.\d+.\d+/.msi").split('/')[3]
- ("C:/chef/cache/Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-'/\d.\d+.\d+/'.msi").split('/')[3]
- ("C:/chef/cache/Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-'\d.\d+.\d+'.msi").split('/')[3]
- ("C:/chef/cache/Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-'(\d.\d+.\d+').msi").split('/')[3]
- ("C:/chef/cache/Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-('/\d.\d+.\d+/').msi").split('/')[3]
- ("C:/chef/cache/Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-('\d.\d+.\d+').msi").split('/')[3]

Comment: This is what we tried   
("C:/chef/cache/Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-/\d.\d+.\d+/.msi").split('/')[3]
("C:/chef/cache/Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-'/\d.\d+.\d+/'.msi").split('/')[3]
("C:/chef/cache/Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-'\d.\d+.\d+'.msi").split('/')[3]
("C:/chef/cache/Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-'(\d.\d+.\d+').msi").split('/')[3]
("C:/chef/cache/Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-('/\d.\d+.\d+/').msi").split('/')[3]
("C:/chef/cache/Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-('\d.\d+.\d+').msi").split('/')[3]

Comment: what is the output you required?

Comment: I want like this "Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-1.181.539.msi"

Comment: `'C:/chef/cache/Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-1.625.235.msi'.split('/').last` try this

Comment: I know this, but in "Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-1.625.235.msi'" those numbers will changing every time, some times it is Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-1.625.235.msi' and some time it is  Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-1.181.539.msi, like that

Comment: There is only difference with the numbers only right? and you're splitting and getting last string only, what's the difference?

Comment: I don't want hard code that "1.625.235" in that script, This file will get from another location in run time, If my string match like above then it split

Comment: irrespective of whatever number comes you only want to show this? "1.625.235"

Comment: Not that, I want "Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-x.xxx.xxx.msi"

Answer (score 4):

If the output you want is always the filename at the end of a path, you could also use `File.basename`.

```rb
string = "C:/chef/cache/Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-1.625.235.msi"
output = File.basename(string) # => "Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-1.625.235.msi"
```

Comment: Not that, I want "Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-x.xxx.xxx.msi" ,  in "Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-1.625.235.msi'" those numbers will changing every time, some times it is Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-1.625.235.msi' and some time it is Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-1.181.539.msi, In this path "C:/chef/cache/" that msi file will be change every time with different versions. Irrespective of version i want pick that msi file......

Comment: It is work, if i hard coded that numbers in then given string. but i don;t wan that...

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're having. The value of `string` is hardcoded in this example for demonstration purposes. Its value could come from anywhere, and `File.basename` should return "Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-x.xxx.xxx.msi" regardless of what the numbers are.

Comment: So change the argument you send to `File.basename` to whatever the source of the value is. `File.basename(read_line_from_file)`. It doesn't matter. The `string` variable is ONLY an example.

Answer (score 2):

```
string="C:/chef/cache/Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-1.625.235.msi"

p string.split("/").last
```

output

```
"Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-1.625.235.msi"
```

Comment: Not that, I want "Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-x.xxx.xxx.msi" , in "Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-1.625.235.msi'" those numbers will changing every time, some times it is Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-1.625.235.msi' and some time it is Dynatrace-OneAgent-Windows-1.181.539.msi, In this path "C:/chef/cache/" that msi file will be change every time with different versions. Irrespective of version i want pick that msi file....